# laravel 5 download file from public folder

Tags: php, ajax

i want to download file from public folder using ajax in laravel 5 
my ajax is

```
$.ajax({
    url:'{{ url() }}/FileManager/downloadfile',
    type:'post',
    data:{file_name:tableData[0],dir_path:selected_row.attr('dir'),is_cloud:tableData[2]},
    success:function(response) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error:function(e) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

and my controller method is

```
public function postDownloadfile(Request $request)
{
    $file_path = public_path().'/'.$request->dir_path.$request->file_name;
    $download_link = link_to_asset($file_path);

    return $download_link;

    $file = FileDB::where("title",$request->file_name)->first();
    $fileType = mime_content_type($file_path);
    $headers = array('Content-Type:'. $fileType,);

    return response()->download($file_path);
}
```

but the result is success but there is no file downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Your postDownloadFile returns the url that should be opened. So in your ajax call:

```
success:function(response) {
    // response is the url that should be downloaded
    window.location = response;
},
```

Also the last four lines of your controller code are ignored because

```
return $download_link;
```

is called before those lines.

Comment: when i use return download_link the returned value is an anchor like that <a%20href="http://localhost:8000/C:/wamp/www/fileManagerUploader/public/content/shop/logo/Hydrangeas.jpg">http://localhost:8000/C:/wamp/www/fileManagerUploader/public/content/shop/logo/Hydrangeas.jpg</a> this make error when open new window Controller method not found.